How to burn large .mp4 files to playable DVDs?
I've got a macOS laptop and I'm attempting to convert old VHS tapes to playable DVDs. I convert the VHS tapes to .mp4 format using OBS and then attempt to burn the .mp4 files to playable DVDs using the Burn app.
The Burn app automatically prompts me to convert to .mpg and it does this conversion for me. That's fine for a few VHS tapes that aren't too long however some are 2+ hours and as a result, the .mp4 files are more than 8GBs which when converted to .mpg, they're greater than the space on a DVD so I'm not able to burn them.
Any ideas how to solve this issue so that I can convert the longer VHS tapes to playable DVDs?

The DVD standard has both 4 and 8GB standards (8.5GB actually) so if your files will fit on that just get bigger recordable DVDs

OP already says they're larger than fit on a DL DVD.

Why are you ripping to MP4 and then converting to MPG?  If you can rip directly to MPG, you'll avoid a second lossy conversion, and get better quality.

@gidds OBS doesn't support saving to .mpg

One option: open the mp4 files in Quicktime; Use the Edit/Trim function to extract segments of each movie that will fit on a DVD; save and then burn each segment onto a different DVD (part 1, part 2, etc.)
